# PostgreSQL vertical partitioning and pluggable storage engines

Tags: postgresql, columnstore

PostgreSQL traditionally stores its data in row-based format but several other DBMSs who have been using vertical / column stores and vectorized execution have been claiming notable performance gains. Also, same can be said for in-memory storage engines.

How can one make use of these techniques through PostgreSQL? Is there some extension or support for things like pluggable storage engines that let somebody change their PostgreSQL to use these feature?

Answer (score 0):

There is [cstore_fdw](https://github.com/citusdata/cstore_fdw) which uses the foreign data wrapper API to implement a column store, and there is [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20160812231527.GA690404@alvherre.pgsql) and [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20180703070645.wchpu5muyto5n647@alap3.anarazel.de) patch for pluggable storage in the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It seems that native column store is quite far away from being introduced. What do you think would be the differences between cstore_fdw and native cstore? Major performance differences? Large implementation effort?

Comment: No idea. As you say, this is too far away yet.

Comment: I am struggling to understand how cstr_fdw works in the sense why is it a fdw? what is it connecting to?

Comment: Taking into account recent acquisition of citus by MSFT we might  see some progress in this area